# How to update all instances of a custom control in a WinForms app after adding a new button

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I am working on a production WinForms app that utilizes a custom control, specifically a proprietary custom searchlookupedit from DevExpress.

This control has a combo box and a couple of buttons, and it is used in hundreds of pages throughout the application. We decided to add another button to the control, and after compilation, we added the updated control to a page, which worked as intended.

However, instances of the button added before the changes remain the same.

After some searching I realized that the constructor of the control is basically copied in the .designer.cs file of the page where you place it in, thus, after changing the "original" constructor, all other instances remain the same.

(Deleting and re-adding every control in the app is not really an option as it would take eons.)

Edit: For clarification, when i said "it copies over the constructor", i meant that it copies over properties. If you create a custom control from a CheckEdit (let's say), add some colors, some text and so on, when you add it to a page, the desinger.cs file will actually contain those same properties. **This is a theory, from what i observed.**

This is the constructor for my custom control:

```cs
InitializeComponent();
this.Size = new Size(217, 24);
this.SelectFirstElement = false;
this.SelectDefaultPartnerOwnerID = true;
this.Filters = new PartnersFilters();
this.Properties.View.Columns.AddField("Name").Visible = true;

this.Properties.ValueMember = "Id";
this.Properties.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.Properties.NullText = string.Empty;
this.Properties.ShowFooter = false;
this.Properties.Buttons.Clear();
this.Properties.Buttons.AddRange(new EditorButton[] {
    new EditorButton(ButtonPredefines.Combo, "Combo", -1, true, true, false, ImageLocation.MiddleCenter, null, new DevExpress.Utils.KeyShortcut(Keys.None), null, "", null, null, false),
    new EditorButton(ButtonPredefines.Glyph, "Find", -1, true, true, false, ImageLocation.MiddleCenter, ListsControls.Properties.Resources.findBTN, new DevExpress.Utils.KeyShortcut(Keys.None), null, "", null, null, false),
    new EditorButton(ButtonPredefines.Delete, "Delete", -1, true, true, false, ImageLocation.MiddleCenter, null, new DevExpress.Utils.KeyShortcut(Keys.None), null, "", null, null, false)});

this.ButtonClick += PartnerLookupEdit_ButtonClick;
this.BeforePopup += PartnerLookupEdit_BeforePopup;
this.Popup += PartnerLookupEdit_PopUp;
this.Paint += PartnerLookupEdit_Paint;
```

and this is what happens when you add the control to a page:

```cs
// 
// luePartnerOwner
// 
this.luePartnerOwner.EnterMoveNextControl = true;
this.luePartnerOwner.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(126, 2);
this.luePartnerOwner.MenuManager = this.barManager1;
this.luePartnerOwner.Name = "luePartnerOwner";
editorButtonImageOptions3.EnableTransparency = false;
editorButtonImageOptions4.EnableTransparency = false;
editorButtonImageOptions5.EnableTransparency = false;
this.luePartnerOwner.Properties.Buttons.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton[] {
new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton(DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Combo, "Combo", -1, true, true, false, editorButtonImageOptions3, new DevExpress.Utils.KeyShortcut(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.None), serializableAppearanceObject9, serializableAppearanceObject10, serializableAppearanceObject11, serializableAppearanceObject12, "", null, null, DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipAnchor.Default),
new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton(DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Glyph, "Find", -1, true, true, false, editorButtonImageOptions4, new DevExpress.Utils.KeyShortcut(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.None), serializableAppearanceObject13, serializableAppearanceObject14, serializableAppearanceObject15, serializableAppearanceObject16, "", null, null, DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipAnchor.Default),
new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton(DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Delete, "Delete", -1, true, true, false, editorButtonImageOptions5, new DevExpress.Utils.KeyShortcut(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.None), serializableAppearanceObject17, serializableAppearanceObject18, serializableAppearanceObject19, serializableAppearanceObject20, "", null, null, DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipAnchor.Default)});
this.luePartnerOwner.Properties.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.luePartnerOwner.Properties.NullText = "";
this.luePartnerOwner.Properties.ShowFooter = false;
this.luePartnerOwner.Properties.ValueMember = "Id";
this.luePartnerOwner.SelectDefaultPartnerOwnerID = true;
this.luePartnerOwner.SelectedID = null;
this.luePartnerOwner.SelectedItem = null;
this.luePartnerOwner.SelectFirstElement = false;
this.luePartnerOwner.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(263, 22);
this.luePartnerOwner.StyleController = this.layoutControl1;
this.luePartnerOwner.TabIndex = 0;
conditionValidationRule4.ConditionOperator = DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider.ConditionOperator.NotEquals;
conditionValidationRule4.ErrorText = "This value is not valid";
this.dxValidationProvider1.SetValidationRule(this.luePartnerOwner, conditionValidationRule4);
```

Now, this is a problem for me because, as I said, I now have 4 buttons instead of 3, but those changed don't carry over even after updating references, rebuilding and everything else I could think of.

Comment: In the `.designer.cs` file, only default Constructors are called. It's not clear whether you have overloaded the Constructor to change behavior. In any case, you have to call the default Constructor in your custom classes -- You may want to post the changes you have made in your Custom Control

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you want to change the behavior of your custom control's constructor, you would typically create additional constructors in your custom control's code (not in the .designer.cs file) by overloading the constructor.

Comment: didn't change the .designer.cs file. I added the control with the gui designer